# Field Formatter Class and limit number of characters

Tags: theming

I have to insert in a field (admin/structure/types/manage/article/display) a string of classes to get a button from a text but the "Field Formatter Class" field has a character limit so I can't enter the code which I need to get the result.
I did some research but couldn't find the solution.

My Class:
btn btn-sm btn-primary stpe-outlinebutton test-util-color-primary test-util-border-primary test-util-hover-background-primary test-util-hover-color-white test-util-hover-border-primary

Any help?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the module [Field Formatter Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) to have this option for your fields.

The module does not set a maximum value for this field. So I believe it is using a default of 128 chars in core.

128 is a fairly long limit for a class field. But if you want to alter this you can write an alter function in your module like they have done in their module and set the #maxlength property of the field_formatter_class element.

Having said that, the following is a quick hack to get this working for you.

You can open the file `field_formatter_class/field_formatter_class.module`

and add a line

```
'#maxlength' => 256,
```

in the element class array in the alter function in line 44. After modification this will be like the following ([view original code](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/field_formatter_class/blob/8.x-1.x/field_formatter_class.module))

```
function field_formatter_class_field_formatter_settings_form_alter(&$settings_form, $context) {
  $display = $context['instance']['display'][$context['view_mode']];
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $settings_form['field_formatter_class'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Field Formatter Class'),
    '#maxlength' => 256,
    '#default_value' => $settings['field_formatter_class'],
  );
```

Do note that this is modifying a contrib module and is generally not a recommended approach. You will have to maintain this patch in a patches folder.

Comment: Thank you very much..

Comment: Hope that solved your problem.